# Convergence and $\Delta$-convergence in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be $\Delta$-convergent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-convergence to $x\in X$ if for every $y\in X$,
$$\limsup\Big(d(x_k,x)-d(x_k,y)\Big)\leq0.$$

I have read that in Hilbert space, $\Delta$-convergence and weak convergence coincide.

Can someone show me the difference between the usual convergence and $\Delta$-convergence, possibly with an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "show me the difference"??  Obviously this definition is totally different from the usual definition of convergence.  What would need explanation is how these two totally different-looking definitions might actually be the same in some cases.

Comment: @EricWofsey these definitions might indeed be different in some other cases. Apparently that is what OP is after

Comment: @EricWofsey possibly an example which is $\Delta$-convergent but not convergent.

Comment: can you add to the question, where did you find this notion of $\Delta$-convergence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen this notion before, I find it interesting, and here are some observations that I believe answer your question.

1. If $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then $(x_n)$ is $\Delta$-convergent to $x$.
   Proof. Trivial, $\limsup\Big(d(x_k,x)-d(x_k,y)\Big)=
   0-\limsup d(x_k,y)\le0$.
2. If $(x_n)$ is convergent (to some point), and if $(x_n)$ is $\Delta$-convergent to $x$, then $(x_n)$ is convergent to $x$. In other words, if $(x_n)$ is convergent to $p$, and if $(x_n)$ is $\Delta$-convergent to $x$, then $x=p$.
   Proof. Trivial.
   Suppose $(x_n)$ is convergent to $p$, and $(x_n)$ is $\Delta$-convergent to $x$, and towards a contradiction, that $x\not=p$. Take $y=p$ then
   $\limsup\Big(d(x_k,x)-d(x_k,p)\Big)=
   d(p,x)-d(p,p)>0$.
   (Well, it was unnecessary to consider case 2 separate from case 1, but I already did just that. But, in case 2, if $(x_n)$ is convergent to $p$, then by case 1 it immediately follows that 
   $(x_n)$ is $\Delta$-convergent to $p$.)
3. Again just a trivial example, but it provides an answer. Take any infinite set with the discrete metric 
   $d(p,q)=1$ if $p\not=q$. Take any infinite sequence 
   $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\not=x_m$ if $n\not=m$.
   Then (following the definition provided by OP), such a sequence is $\Delta$-convergent to $x$, for every $x$.
   Indeed, given any $x$ and any $y$, for all large enough $k$ we would have $x_k\not=x$ and $x_k\not=y$, hence 
   $\limsup\Big(d(x_k,x)-d(x_k,y)\Big)=
   1-1\le0$.
   (Clearly the sequence here is not convergent to any $x$, it is not even a Cauchy sequence.)

Edit. 9/26. I have some other easy remarks, just to help develop some intuition. Note there is some background info in a new answer by 
@postmortes, indicating there are two definitions 
of $\Delta-$convergence. I copy the following paragraph from @postmortes' answer:

--- What's given by the OP is actually the definition of *strong* $\Delta-$convergence.  Ordinary $\Delta-$convergence to a point $x$ is given by
$$ \lim \sup_{i\in {\mathbb N}} d(x_{n_k}, x)\leq \lim \sup_{i\in {\mathbb N}} d(x_{n_k}, y)$$
for any subsequence $\{{x_{n_k}}\}_{k \in {\mathbb N}}$ of $\{x_n\}_{n \in {\mathbb N}}$ and every $y\in E\ $ where $(E,d)$ is a metric space.  Obviously strong $\Delta-$convergence implies $\Delta-$convergence. ---

So, in the following I would use terms strong $\Delta-$convergence and ordinary $\Delta-$convergence (instead of $\Delta-$convergence) to avoid possible confusion.

Clearly results 1,2,3, above remain valid for both definitions.

I had some observations about subsequences, but do not remember them anymore, perhaps they were not much different (in spirit) than what is already available in Teck-Cheong Lim's paper. Only thing I remember from this morning is the following. (It is rather easy, and perhaps not any important, but just for the record.)

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is an unbounded sequence in $\Bbb R^m$, for some finite $m\ge1$. Then 
$(x_n)$ is not $\Delta$-convergent.
Proof. (for the definition of $\Delta$-convergence as in OP.) If $s_n$ is the (central) projection of $x_n$ onto the unit sphere $S$ then $(s_n)$ has a convergent subsequence 
$s_{n_k}\to s$, as $k\to\infty$. We may also assume that $x_{n_k}\to\infty$ (i.e. for any $z$ we have $d(z,x_{n_k})\to\infty$). Take any $x$ and let $y=2(|x|+1)s$. (The idea is, that $y$ is "between" $x$ and "the tails" of $(x_{n_k})$. 
Then $\limsup\Big(d(x_k,x)-d(x_k,y)\Big)\ge1$ 
(this might need some details, but I think a picture might help.)

Comment: +1, of course, this makes me want to find an example where the limsup is genuinely needed, and also one where one obtains $<0$ instead of $=0\le 0$...

Comment: @Mirko yes, the definition given in the question is of Strong $\Delta$-convergence which I came to know after referring to the cited papers. And thanks for your insightful remarks!

Answer (score 2):

This is rather supplementary to Mirko's answer but is far too long to be tucked into the comments.  This provides some background and references.

What's given by the OP is actually the definition of *strong* $\Delta-$convergence.  Ordinary $\Delta-$convergence to a point $x$ is given by
$$ \lim \sup_{i\in {\mathbb N}} d(x_{n_k}, x)\leq \lim \sup_{i\in {\mathbb N}} d(x_{n_k}, y)$$
for any subsequence $\{{x_{n_k}}\}_{k \in {\mathbb N}}$ of $\{x_n\}_{n \in {\mathbb N}}$ and every $y\in E\ $ where $(E,d)$ is a metric space.  Obviously strong $\Delta-$convergence implies $\Delta-$convergence.

$\Delta-$convergence appears to have been introduced by T-C. Lim in https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-060-01/S0002-9939-1976-0423139-X/S0002-9939-1976-0423139-X.pdf and is related to, but distinct from, *polar convergence*:
$$ x_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} x \mbox{ if }\  \forall y \not= x \ \exists M_y \in {\mathbb N} \ \mbox{ such that }\ d(x_n,x) < d(x_n,y)\ \forall n\geq M_y  $$
Polar convergence implies $\Delta-$convergence, but the limit points do not even have to be equal.

$\Delta-$convergence is also connected to *asymptotic radii* and *centres*: a sequence $\{x_n\}$ $\Delta-$converges to $x\in E$ iff $x$ is an asymptotic centre of every subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$, and strongly $\Delta-$converges to $x$ if every subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ has the same asymptotic radius $r$.

For a much more in-depth survey and references I would suggest reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.6463.pdf

Comment: Hi, Thanks, very informative. I was just thinking that the definition felt a bit too strong. I was also thinking of some cases when $(x_n)$ is unbounded, and whether that happens in $\Bbb R^m$ or in an infinite-dimensional space. Also, cases depending on whether $(x_n)$ contains a subsequence that is Cauchy ... just some cases that might be easy to deal with, yet provide some intuition. I may add something to my answer (sticking with the definition as in OP, for now... though I will see, it appears my answer applies to both strong and ordinary $\delta$-convergence). May take me a few days...

Comment: @Mirko: if you're updating your answer feel free to take the useful bits of this too.  Ping me when you're done and I'll delete it, so we have a single, good answer to the  question :)

Comment: I already "stole" one paragraph from your answer without asking :) But I don't feel like copying too much, and I feel it might be better to keep the two answers separate, in particular your answer is much better regarding background and available references (and why would you refuse the upvotes ...).

Comment: @Mirko -- take all you like :) I'll leave my answer for now then, but I'm not too bothered about reputation: I have enough now to be useful (hopefully) on the site.